# Java Spring JPA - How to correctly map multiple tables with OneToMany and such

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am making a database project using Spring Boot and I have a model in mind that utilizes multiple tables. In this model of mine I thought about having a main table and using some of the attributes of this table as a primary key for the others, but I don't want to store, say, lists of others tables inside as seems to be the case for people when they use the @OneToMany tag and others. As you may guess, I'm new to database design.

Below, there is a simplified scheme of what I want to do.
[image]

My main questions here are:

1. Is this good practice / good database design?
2. Is this doable in Java Spring? If so, how? What annotations would I need to use and where?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*My main questions ...*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: The diagram is incomplete, it is missing the cardinality of relations. --- Do not use a foreign key of one table as primary key of another table (excl. join tables). --- I would always suggest to use a technical primary key, i.e. some kind of sequence. --- What is described sound more like `@ManyToOne` relations (as seen from `EncodingResult`, a result has one encoding, one encoding can be used in multipel results). --- the `float result`s seem like a candidate for a `@OneToMany`-relationship (as seen from `EncodingResult`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Person and Mobile number is the best example for one-to-many relationship.
> Because one person can have multiple mobile numbers, and for the mobile number
> perspective multiple mobile numbers refers to one person.

For the person entity there will be field like below :
id, name, city, mobile_number_id [foreign key] which will holds id from mobile entity

For the mobile entity there will be field like below :
id, mobile_number